# Does list.index() implement caching

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, caching, methods

In Python, does the `list.index()` method implement caching?

In other words, If I do

```
myList = [3,5,4,7]
print myList.index(5) 
print myList.index(5)
```

Does the second invocation of the method have to iterate over the array, or is the method smart enough to know that it already has an answer for the input: 5?

*obviously, any time the array is modified the cache would be invalidated and would thus have to be cleared*

Comment: [See the implementation](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listobject.c) - The answer is **no**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find out by doing a simple profiling.

```
import cProfile,random
def scrambled(orig): # scramble list
    dest = orig[:]
    random.shuffle(dest)
    return dest

myList = scrambled(range(0,10000000))

cProfile.run('print myList.index(1)') #3 func, same amount of time
cProfile.run('print myList.index(1)') #3 func, same amount of time
```

thus **no**.